Can we say that $|x^{p}-y^{p}| \leq C (|x|^{p-1}+|y|^{p-1}) |x-y|$?
Let $x, y \in \mathbb C$ and $p>1.$

Question: Can we say that $|x^{p}-y^{p}| \leq C (|x|^{p-1}+|y|^{p-1}) |x-y|$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb C$ and $C$ is some constant?

Note: Clearly  the above inequality hold for $p=2$. I'm interested to know for which other $p$ the above inequality holds?

The duplicate target is about real numbers, but the same approach works for complex numbers: $|x^p - y^p| \le p \int_x^y |z|^{p-1} |dz| $ ...
